# How to add prerequisite installation in the .msi output file of Setup Project using VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, prerequisites

I am a newbie in creating the setup projects and I have created a "myfirstSetup" project. Its working good, but it has a dependency or I should say a prerequisite to be installed before its installation. I want that prerequisite to be installed during my project installation.

Till now I have done following things :

1.) Added the prerequisite by going myfirstSetup Properties 
2.) Select the prerequisite 
3.) Check the Download Prerequisite from the same location as my application

The .exe that is being created is installing the prerequisite but the .msi is only installing my project.

any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it works - the setup.exe installs prerequisites and then your MSI installs your project. There are many reasons for this. Is there an actual problem or do you just believe your MSI file should be able to install prerequisites like the .NET framework, SQL Express and so on?

Comment: An msi file, which can install all the prerequisites silently is the requirement.

Comment: Bad luck. That's impossible with VS setup projects. Bootstrappers that install prerequisites are not just a choice - they are a necessity.